# "Unable to set AuthPassword" ssmtp

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, smtp, ssmtp

I am setting up smtp to sent mails via terminal and getting "non-zero" status.
In my log files there is a log about "Unable to set AuthPassword"
password contains characters and numbers.

ssmtp.conf:

```
 1 #
 2 # Config file for sSMTP sendmail
 3 #
 4 # The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
 5 # Make this empty to disable rewriting.
 6 root=lukas.kotyza@outlook.com
 7 AuthUser=lukas.kotyza@outlook.com
 8 AuthPassword=word12345
 9 UseTLS=YES
10 UseSTARTTLS=YES
11 
12 # The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
13 # MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
14 mailhub=smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
15 
16 # Where will the mail seem to come from?
17 #rewriteDomain=
18 rewriteDomain=outlook.com
19 
20 # The full hostname
21 hostname=lukas.kotyza@outlook.com
22 
23 
24 # Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
25 # YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
26 # NO - Use the system generated From: address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page for `ssmtp.conf`:

> AuthPass
> The password to use for SMTP AUTH.

You've configured `ssmtp.conf` with `AuthPassword`, which it doesn't appear to be expecting. Try it with the flag from the man page.

You should also redact passwords, at least in my opinion, when posting questions!